# Java How to set motion onTouchEvent to certain objects only

Tags: java, android, touch-event

Recently, I have learnt from some tutorials how to make any part of the screen receive touch input, but I wonder how to give `onTouchEvent` only to certain object pressed. I have also researched that if I want to do so I need to have the class of the object extend View (although I'm still not sure how to do it). Unfortunately, my class have extended another class. 
So how to set the `onTouchEvent` only to player object?
P.S. Currently my code receives touch events from any part of the screen touched.

Main code :

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
public GamePanel(Context context){
    super(context);

    //Add callback to the surfaceview to intercept events
    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    //Make GamePanel focusable so it can handle events
    setFocusable(true);
}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
    bg = new Background(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.background));
    player = new Player(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.character),WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2+40,80,75,14);
    bouncer = new ArrayList<Bouncer>();

    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);

    //Start the game loop
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();

}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        //if not jumping
        if(!player.getIsJumping() && !player.getFall()) {
            //set temp to store distance that should be travelled
            double temp = 1.06 * (bouncer.get(bouncerIndex).getY()-bouncer.get(bouncerIndex+1).getY());
            //setDy based on s = v0*t + 1/2*a*t^2
            player.setDy(((int)Math.ceil((temp+450)/30))*-1);
            player.setIsJumping(true);
            jumpStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        }
        return true;
    }
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
}
```

Player code :

```
 public class Player extends GameObject{
 public Player(Bitmap res,int x, int y,int w,int h, int numFrames){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        height = h;
        width = w;

        Bitmap[] image = new Bitmap[numFrames];
        spritesheet = res;

        for(int i=0;i<image.length;i++){
            if(i%7==0 && i>0)row++;
            image[i] = Bitmap.createBitmap(spritesheet,(i-7*row)*width,row*height,width,height);
        }
        animation.setFrames(image);
        animation.setDelay(200);
    }
}
```

Game Object code :

```
public abstract class GameObject {
protected int x;
protected int y;
protected int width;
protected int height;
protected int dx;
protected int dy;

public void setX(int x){
    this.x = x;
}

public void setY(int y){
    this.y = y;
}

public int getX(){
    return x;
}

public int getY(){
    return y;
}
}
```

Sorry for the untidy codes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Right here `if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)`. This is probably why

> Currently my code receives touch events from any part of the screen touched.

How about setting an `ontouchlistener` to the player only rather than implementing it?

something like;

```
player.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {               
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {             

            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.i("PLAYER", "image has been touched"); 
             //if not jumping
               if(!player.getIsJumping() && !player.getFall()) {
            //set temp to store distance that should be travelled
              double temp = 1.06 * (bouncer.get(bouncerIndex).getY()-      bouncer.get(bouncerIndex+1).getY());
            //setDy based on s = v0*t + 1/2*a*t^2
              player.setDy(((int)Math.ceil((temp+450)/30))*-1);
              player.setIsJumping(true);
              jumpStartTime = System.nanoTime();
                }  


                break;


            }               
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't work. Cannot resolve symbol 'setOnTouchListener' and  'event'. I think maybe they do not work because GamePanel extends SurfaceView and is not my MainActivity class, just a class where all the game mechanics work called by MainActivity. Sorry, I've edited a bit of my code to give further information. Still need help. Thanks

Comment: I mean, If i'm not wrong setOnTouchListener only works if the class extends Activity or View right? Since my class doesn't extends Activity nor View I don't know how to use setOnTouchListener.